# onClick Function based on Radio Labels

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, label

I have a few radio buttons with their corresponding labels. I want to create a javascript code so that if a person clicks on a certain label, it will change one particular image that has the ID of "largeimage".

So, by clicking these labels/radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="thumbnails" value="thumbnail_ver1" id="thumbnail_ver1">
<label for="thumbnail_ver1">Color option 1.</label>

<input type="radio" name="thumbnails" value="thumbnail_ver2" id="thumbnail_ver2">
<label for="thumbnail_ver2">Color option 2.</label>

<input type="radio" name="thumbnails" value="thumbnail_ver3" id="thumbnail_ver3">
<label for="thumbnail_ver3">Color option 3.</label>

<input type="radio" name="thumbnails" value="thumbnail_ver4" id="thumbnail_ver4">
<label for="thumbnail_ver4">Color option 4.</label>

<input type="radio" name="thumbnails" value="thumbnail_ver5" id="thumbnail_ver5">
<label for="thumbnail_ver5">Color option 5.</label>
```

Will cause this image that has the ID of "largeimage":

```
<img src="largeimage_original.jpg" id="largeimage" width="230px" height="330px" alt="Large Image" />
```

To change the "largeimage" into one the following images depending on which label option/radio button is currently selected:

```
largeimage_ver1.jpg
largeimage_ver2.jpg
largeimage_ver3.jpg
largeimage_ver4.jpg
largeimage_ver5.jpg
```

I've tried multiple onClick functions to no avail. Suggestions?

Comment: You tried passing 'this' as a parameter for 'onClick'? Doesn't onClick get triggered at all? Because that code does nothing along the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var radios = document.forms["yourFormName"].elements["thumbnails"];

for (var i = 0, max = radios.length; i < max; i++) {
    radios[i].addEventListener("click", replaceImage, false); 
}

function replaceImage() {
    for (var i = 0, max = radios.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            imgID = (radios[i].value).replace("thumbnail_", "");
            document.getElementById("largeimage").src = "largeimage_" + imgID + ".jpg";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```